# Transit visa for Indian citizen when transiting through China

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, china, canadian-residents

I am an Indian citizen and a permanent resident of Canada. I am considering the following flight:

> Delhi (DEL) -> Hong Kong (HKG) -> Beijing (PEK) -> Montreal (YUL)

I have a 2hr layover in Hong Kong and 2h15m layover in Beijing.

Based on [this website](http://ee.china-embassy.org/eng/tzygg/t1460983.htm), I will not need a transit visa but I am not 100% sure about the terminology (holds tickets to a third country). I would appreciate if someone could confirm that they have traveled through China under similar circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to website, you do not require transit Visa, as you will be having the onward ticket to Canada.

First Country they mention is Hong Kong (See comment below), Second is China and Third is Canada, if you are confused by the terminology.

Comment: For China 24-hour and 72-hour transits, Hong Kong and Macau are considered separate regions ([Source](https://www.forbes.com/sites/johnnyjet/2018/03/01/transit-china-without-a-visa-twov/#3952057e1151)). OP's itinerary is India - Hong Kong-China-Canada in relation to Chinese terminology.

Comment: @RedBaron Updated the answer.